# SQL-Java Data type mapping

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, type-conversion

I would like to map the data types of Java and SQL, for example :

```
SQL QUERY DATATYPE - JAVA DATATYPE

VarCharValue - String

FloatValue - double
```

Hence, I would like to know more for Reference Types, Boolean Types, DataTime Types

Thanks

Comment: Might want to do a search before posting next time :) [That link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm) was the first result when searching for your question title:  `SQL Java Data type mapping`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I think you will find everything [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm)